# How compress a very high image to share on Facebook, Twitter or Whatsapp?

Tags: java, android, facebook, twitter, whatsapp

I am creating an app for sharing texts in images. 
The problem I have is that I generate a very high image. Depending on the text it can be to 20000 pixels of height and 1500 pixels width. Even though compress image before upload, when I share it on Twitter, Facebook or Whatsapp; the text of the image looks blurred and is impossible to read.

I guess that these social networks compression has to do with the height of the image. I thought that, if putting the text into smaller columns to make the square image, perhaps the problem is corrected.
Does anyone know a trick so that the compression of social networks do not modify the texts on the images? Thanks a lot

Comment: It most likely just has to do with scaling.  If you have a 20K height and compress it to 1K height for display, you have to shrink it by a factor of 20.  Nothing is going to stop that from being blurry.

Comment: No one will be able to view that full image on Facebook anyway – even if I view it in the photo detail view and fullscreen mode, that image will be scaled down by a factor 10 to 20 – so most likely the text will still not even be readable.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just did a test by the square image and the result is satisfactory. The rectangle of 1000px * 20000px have turned it into a "square" of 5500 x 6000 and the text is read correctly. Thanks a lot